# Parse HTML and retrieve text from element as a JSON

Tags: html, json, get, html-parsing

I’m a complete newbie to this. But I'd like to retrieve text from html. I’ve inspected my apps elements and have a class id to what I want.

What would I need to insert in the Java script to both parse the html code and retrieve the text in the "rbc-toolbar-label"

Like I said, I’m a newbie but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

For now I have something like this:

Get the element by its ID

```
var element = document.getElementById("rbc-toolbar-label");

// Get the text content of the element

var text = element.textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly so you want to parse html through javascript so you can do that by following steps. if it is not your answer, please elaborate your questions so I can understand.

Step 1: Create an HTML element using JavaScript:
To create an HTML element in JavaScript, you can use the `document.createElement()` method. This method allows you to create a new HTML element that can be customized and manipulated before it is added to the web page.

Example:

```
var temporaryDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

Step 2: Extract HTML content from an existing HTML element:
To get the HTML content from an existing HTML element, you can use the `innerHTML` property. This property contains the complete HTML content inside the selected element, including its child elements, text, and attributes.

Example:

```
var htmlContent = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Step 3: Inject HTML content into the `temporaryDiv`:
To insert the HTML content into the newly created `temporaryDiv`, you can assign the extracted `htmlContent` to the `innerHTML` property of the `temporaryDiv`. This will set the content of the `temporaryDiv` to be the same as the HTML content you extracted in Step 2.

Example:

```
temporaryDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
```

By following these steps, you will be able to parse and manipulate HTML content using JavaScript, allowing you to create, modify, or extract specific parts of the HTML document dynamically. This technique can be particularly useful for generating dynamic content, building user interfaces, or handling data retrieved from external sources.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was after, to clarify though, I don't want to create a new html element. I just want the text imbedded within that element. Preferably sent to a sheet cell. I also would like that to trigger when a particular link is clicked on the website. Does that make sense?